# What is the integral closure of the integers in the real numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

What is the integral closure of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ inside the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers and what are it's properties? Is this studied at all?

Answer (score 4):

The real [algebraic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer); that is, the intersection of $\mathbb{R}$ and the algebraic integers in $\mathbb{C}$. It's generally more profitable to study all algebraic integers since, for example, the Galois conjugates of a real algebraic integer need not be real.